# How to set environment variable for hosting and port

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, port, hostname

I have a coding like this

```
var express = require('express');
var app=express();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var Db=require('mongodb').Db;
var Server=require('mongodb').Server;
var client=new Db('healthdata' , new Server('127.0.0.1',27017),{safe:false});

client.open(function(err,pClient)
{
  client.collection('userdetails',function(err,collection)
  {
    Ucollection=collection;
  });
});

app.listen(8080,'192.168.0.1');
```

I have run my application by using port and local ip address like above so how to set environment variable for hostnames and port for both node and mongodb. explain me with coding.

Answer (score 10):

Node.js is able to access environment variables using `process.env.XXX` where `XXX` is the name of the variable you want to access.

One usual solution for your question is to define an environment variable, e.g. `PORT` which contains the port number, and then access it as `process.env.PORT`.

As you can not guarantee that this environment variable is set under every circumstance, you'll usually also include a fallback, such as:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

For the IP address, it's basically the same:

```
var ip = process.env.IP || '192.168.178.1';
```

Then you can do:

```
var ip = process.env.IP || '192.168.178.1',
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, ip);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: app.liste(port,'192.168.0.2') it is working but instead of ip address how can i give?

Comment: Use `var ip = process.env.IP || '192.168.178.1';` inside of Node and define an environment variable called `IP`.

Comment: how to set environment variable for hosting and port for mongo

Comment: In exactly the same way. I expect you to figure this out for yourself. It's not harder than copy / paste and adjusting the name.